# Mysql Query Find all the departments that make an average salary greater than the average salary of instructors working in the Finance department

Tags: mysql

I am trying to Find all the departments that make an average salary greater than the average salary of instructors working in the Finance department.

the tables are;
department(dept_name,building,budget)
instructor(ID,name,dept_name,salary)

```
            SELECT 
    *
FROM
    instructor e
        JOIN
    department ON e.dept_name = e.dept_name
WHERE
    salary > (SELECT 
            AVG(salary)
        FROM
            instructor e2
        WHERE
            dept_name = 'Finance');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT d.dept_name
FROM department d
INNER JOIN instructor i
    ON i.dept_name = d.dept_name
GROUP BY d.dept_name
HAVING AVG(i.salary) > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM instructor WHERE dept_name = 'Finance');
```

Answer (score -1):

select dept_name, avg(salary) from instructor group by dept_name Having avg(salary) > (Select avg(salary) from instructor where dept_name='Finance');

Comment: Your answer can be more readable by using the "Code Sample" option in the editor. Simply select the code part of your answer and click on "Code Sample" button or use the Ctrl+K shortcut.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35327032)